# VSCode: Access native language servers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to access Visual Studio Code's native language server to get information about code. In my case I need a list of all Javascript functions from a javascript or typescript file.

I have seen VSCode extensibility API, and see documentation on how to create language server, but haven't found anything on how to access existing language servers and query them for information.

Comment: From where do you want this information? An extension? Command line?

Comment: I want information in extension